# Use nvd3 within custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I'm getting crazy to let this chunk of code working:

I have few charts to show with different data and I created a single directive to show those charts.

This is the main.html:

```
<div ng-controller="data in server.data">
    <chart data="data.values" diff="getDifference(data.values)"></chart>
```

My directive:

```
return {
      templateUrl: '/views/chart.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '=data',
        diff: '&'
      }
    };
```

My chart template:

```
<nvd3 options="pieOptions" data="{{data}}"></nvd3>
<div class="test-passed-percentage">
  <p>{{diff(data)}}%<span>tests passed</span></p>
</div>
```

If I comment out the `nvd3` directive it work fine. But obviously I need it...

In the console log I have this error:

**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'data' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{data}}] starting at [data}}].**

How can I include the nvd3 directive within my template?

Comment: `Nothing work...` what exactly doesn't work? did you get any Exceptions?

Comment: as a side note: `getDifference` I would write in common servie/factory

Comment: 1. Is your directive name really `result`, not `results`? 2. That's not the way we pass argument to function obtained by the `&` method.

Comment: everything is fine, I have no errors in console... it just render this in the browser: `{{diff(data)}}` rather than the value...

Comment: Working one: http://plnkr.co/edit/MhY3AYk4MNKvLhvseIO1?p=preview

Comment: but what is: `ng-controller="data in server.data"`??

Comment: the data is array of values

Comment: start by properly declaring `ng-controller` . Suggest you create a demo since you have numerous issues within your code

Comment: Token 'data' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{data}}] starting at [data}}].

Comment: ok the issue seems to be the data of the NDV3 chart. How can I allow the ndv3 directive within mine?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<p>{{diff()}}%<span>tests passed</span></p>
```

or this:

```
<p>{{diff({ data: data })}}%<span>tests passed</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is caused by `nvd3` directive.